# Are there any good tools for iOS pseudo localization?

Tags: ios, localization

I'd like to start seeing how comprehensive we've been in our iOS code at localizing strings.  We're not ready to go to translators yet, but I'd like to start testing with [pseudo localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolocalization).  Automating this process in a Localizable.strings file should be easy enough, but I can't seem to find any tools that do it.  Frankly, I'd be satisfied with a script that just changed all my strings to "NOT ENGLISH!" if such a thing exists.

Comment: +1, even though others might flag this as a [shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [Translate Toolkit](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/).

First you need to convert the *.strings* file to *PO* using the [prop2po](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/prop2po.html) converter:

```
$ prop2po Localizable.strings en.po
```

This will create a *PO* file with the strings of the *Localizable.strings* file as source strings (in this case I'm using English as a source).

Once you have the *PO* file, rewrite it using [podebug](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/podebug.html) in the [desired rewrite format](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/option_rewrite.html).

```
$ podebug --rewrite=unicode en.po en_rewritten.po
```

Finally convert it back to the *.strings* format (note that you need to pass the original *Localizable.strings* file as a template):

```
$ po2prop en_rewritten.po rewritten.strings -t Localizable.strings
```

The resulting file will look something like this:

```
"Account: %@" = "Ȧƈƈǿŭƞŧ: %@";

"Add command" = "Ȧḓḓ ƈǿḿḿȧƞḓ";

"Add connection." = "Ȧḓḓ ƈǿƞƞḗƈŧīǿƞ."
```

Comment: YES!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  If anyone looks at this at some point and has trouble installing (I did), where the instructions say to use "su ./setup.py install", use "sudo python ./setup.py install" instead.

Comment: So close, I got the first two steps to work but not the third:   
   
`% po2prop -t Localizable.strings en_rewritten.po rewritten.strings  `
`processing 1 files...`
  
`po2prop: warning: Error processing: input en_rewritten.po, output rewritten.strings, template Localizable.strings: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-11: ordinal not in range(128)
[###########################################] 100%`

Comment: Does your PO file have non-ascii characters in the location comments? If so, [bug 2101](http://bugs.locamotion.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2101) might be related.

Comment: **$ prop2po Localizable.strings en.po** did not work for me. I am getting _prop2po: warning: Error processing: input Localizable.strings, output en.po, template None: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'_ But, I assumed I do not need a template? Hope you can give me a hint.

Comment: I suspect your file's encoding is not what prop2po expects ([.properties file's default encoding is latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties#Format)). You can pass the `--encoding=<encoding>` option, or alternatively convert your file's encoding to latin-1 using `iconv` or a similar tool.

Comment: @spikey The default encoding for strings files is actually UTF-16, although in practice I suspect that UTF-8 is very common.  If your Python environment doesn't have chardet installed, the Translate Toolkit auto-detection for properties files (of which strings files are a subtype) doesn't try very hard to see if some other encoding than the default might work.  Per @julen's suggestion, ``--encoding=utf-8`` would probably solve this problem (utf-8 is the most likely encoding since utf-16 is failing for you, and would work for an ASCII file as well, though not any ISO_8859-* encoding).

Answer (score 4):

I came across two solutions that haven't yet been mentioned here:

- A free app called on the Mac App store that generates pseudolocalized .strings files based on your source code (drag-and-drop). It generates similar strings to those the OP provided in the question.

  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pseudolocalizer/id503026674?mt=12
- The online translation service Babble-on offers free pseudolocalized .strings files based on existing .strings files (other options available). They have the extra option of generating strings longer than the original English to test your GUI.

  http://www.ibabbleon.com/pseudolocalization.html

Comment: The advantage of Babble-on's free service is that you can get two files back: ASIAN (with Chinese characters) that makes it easier to spot untranslated strings, as well as EUROPEAN, which is 30% longer to mimic languages like French and German. That's great for testing your GUI.

Comment: Another quick and free tool is http://www.pseudolocalize.com - One click to get the pseudolocalized version back

Comment: @JerSchneid that cannot work with a Localizable.strings file

Answer (score 3):

although Translate Toolkit can provide a solution I've looked for a simpler approach using bash script.
create [changesDictionary.txt] file (see format at the end of this post) and run the following script with the language file as parameter:

```
#  This script translate iOS strings file into pseudo languge for texting usage.
#  the script create a sed change and replace file based on [changesDictionary.txt].
#  the loop run across the input string file (ie. myFyle.strings)
#    and replace the secong strings with the dictionary values.
#  since the strings file is in BOM format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
#   the input is converted from UTF16 to UTF8.
sed -e 's/^"\(.*\)" = "\(.*\)"$/s\/\1\/\2\/g/' changesDictionary.txt  > changesDictionary.sed

FILENAME=$1

while read -r; do
if [[ $REPLY = '/*'* ]] ; then
    echo "$REPLY"
else
    if [[ $REPLY = '' ]] ; then
        echo "$REPLY"
    else
        if [[ $REPLY = '"'* ]] ; then
            changes2=$(echo "$REPLY" | cut -d= -f2 | sed -f changesDictionary.sed)
            changes1=$(echo "$REPLY" | cut -d= -f1 )
            echo "$changes1=$changes2"
                        echo "$REPLY"
        fi
    fi
fi
done < <(iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 $FILENAME) | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 >$FILENAME.new
```

The script look for a [changeDictionary.txt] file in the following format:

```
"a" = "á"
"b" = "β"
"c" = "ç"
"d" = "δ"
"e" = "è"
"f" = "ƒ"
"g" = "ϱ"
"h" = "λ"
"i" = "ï"
"j" = "J"
"k" = "ƙ"
"l" = "ℓ"
"m" = "₥"
"n" = "ñ"
"o" = "ô"
"p" = "ƥ"
"q" = "9"
"r" = "ř"
"s" = "ƨ"
"t" = "ƭ"
"u" = "ú"
"v" = "Ʋ"
"w" = "ω"
"x" = "ж"
"y" = "¥"
"z" = "ƺ"
"\ñ" = "\n"
"$δ" = "$d"
"$ï" = "$i"
```

you can use this example or create your own, please note tp the last 3 change string in the file. this is to restore end of lines and parameters to their regular state. I chose this approach to simplify the script (I think that the perfomance are not optimized).

Answer (score 1):

We provide pseudo localization as part of our service at Tethras ([www.tethras.com](http://www.tethras.com)). Pseudo localization is free. We accent all of the characters in your strings and extend the length of the text by 30%. This will help you test not only for hard coded strings, but will also let you see what happens to your layouts due to text expansion during translation.

Examples:

Plain Text

> Wè prôvïdè psèúdô lôçálïzátïôñ ás párt ôƒ ôúr sèrvïçè át Tèthrás
>   (www.tèthrás.çôm). ôñè twô thrèè ƒôúr ƒïvè sïx Psèúdô lôçálïzátïôñ ïs
>   ƒrèè. ôñè twô thrèè Wè áççèñt áll ôƒ thè çháráçtèrs ïñ ¥ôúr strïñgs
>   áñd èxtèñd thè lèñgth ôƒ thè tèxt b¥ 30%. ôñè twô thrèè ƒôúr ƒïvè sïx
>   Thïs wïll hèlp ¥ôú tèst ñôt ôñl¥ ƒôr hárd çôdèd strïñgs, bút wïll álsô
>   lèt ¥ôú sèè whát háppèñs tô ¥ôúr lá¥ôúts dúè tô tèxt èxpáñsïôñ dúrïñg
>   tráñslátïôñ. ôñè twô thrèè ƒôúr ƒïvè sïx sèvèñ èïght ñïñè tèñ

Localizable.strings

```
"Bring All to Front" = "Brïñg Áll tô ƒrôñt ôñè twô";
"Hide" = "Hïdè 12";
"Quit" = "Qúït 12";
"Hide Others" = "Hïdè Óthèrs ôñè ";
```

Kudos on wanting to test the localizability of your app prior to translation. This is going to save you a lot of time and energy during the actual translation process.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `genstrings` tool provided by Apple. It's all explained in the strings section of the [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6)

Comment: `genstrings` will generate my Localizable.strings file, which I'm already doing, but it does so with either the keys as values or my default values.  I'm looking for something that will take the output of genstrings and then change the values for psuedo localization.